# Selecting the most current plan for a student

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have very limited knowledge of SQL and have tried 4 different similar solutions offered here and I'm still getting error messages.

I'm using SQL2005.

I want to run a query on a database table (named `plans`) where we store information about students' learning plans. I'd like the query to only grab the most recent plan for a student.  There are many columns, but the columns I'd like to get at for now are...

```
PlanID  
PlanStatus  
PlanDate  
PlanEndDate  
StudentID  
Firstname  
Lastname
```

I hoping to pull just one plan per `StudentID` (the most recent plan). I was planning on using the `PlanDate` to determine what is the most recent plan. I've tried various `JOINS` and `MAX` statements that I've seen in similar questions and each one returns an error message for me.

Comment: You say you have tried some queries, but please _show_ what you have tried. It is much easier to help you fix your broken code than to start from scratch.

Comment: @gunr2127 Thanks - My apologies, I didn't keep track of the various things I tried.  Typically I have great success using this site to find answers to my questions, so I didn't think to track my failures.  I just assumed that if I tried another one, that eventually I'd land on something that would work.  Next time, I'll track the queries I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*
  FROM [plans] A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [plans] B ON B.PlanDate > A.PlanDate 
                           AND B.StudentID = A.StudentID
 WHERE B.PlanID IS NULL
```

This is saying, basically, give me all rows for which there isn't a row with a higher plan date and the same student ID.

Another, equivalent way of writing this query that is perhaps easier for a human to understand but runs much, much slower in Sql Server would be

```
SELECT A.*
  FROM [plans] A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM [plans] B 
                    WHERE B.PlanDate > A.PlanDate 
                      AND B.StudentID = A.StudentID)
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Dan.  It looks like this got me exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate that you made the example perfect for my data.  Sometimes I have a hard time when people use abbreviations or "demo" table names or column names.

Answer (score 1):

This one assumes that there can be PlanDates in the future and 'most recent' means 'the latest, earlier than today'.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
      P.StudentID,
      MAX(P.PlanDate) AS MostRecentPlanDate
    FROM plans P
    WHERE P.PlanDate < GETDATE()
    GROUP BY P.StudentID
)
SELECT P.*
FROM
    plans P
    INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.StudentID = P.StudentID 
      AND CTE.MostRecentPlanDate = p.PlanDate
```

- I made a correction and here is the fiddle:
  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6eb38/3

The CTE (Common Table Expression) selects each student-ID and the corresponding maximum date, but only from those before today. In the main query, this is used by an inner join to filter the wanted rows.

Comment: Why not `GROUP BY` in the cte?

Comment: @KekuSemau Thanks for the Fiddle... didn't know that existed.  Learned a lot today.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
select
    PlanStatus,  
    max(PlanDate) , 
    max(PlanEndDate) , 
    StudentID,  
    Firstname , 
    Lastname
from plans 
group by PlanStatus  , StudentID, Firstname, Lastname
```

Comment: I believe I typed this exactly as you had it written and I got the error message... Incorrect syntax near the keyword "from".  I tried a couple of tweaks, but continued to get the same error message.  It's fine though since I was able to use Dan's example to get at what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: remove the last comma before the from select
    PlanStatus,  
    max(PlanDate) , 
    max(PlanEndDate) , 
    StudentID,  
    Firstname , 
    Lastname
from plans 
group by PlanStatus  , StudentID, Firstname, Lastname